# rJava issue when trying to use ATACseq pipeline

Tags: atac-seq

I am trying to use the following [`ATACseq` pipeline](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/esATAC.html).

Unfortunately when I am importing it with `library(esATAC)`, it is giving me an error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

There are threads that discuss similar problems [1](https://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735108/r-error-onload-failed-in-loadnamespace-for-rjava):

But I checked the Java version and it is the right one: `64bit`:

```
d-172-25-60-75:~ nikitavlasenko$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
```

I tried to do the following in `Rstudio`:

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "/usr/bin/java")
library(rJava)
library(esATAC)
```

But `library(rJava)` fails. I am using macOS High Sierra 10.13.4. I am not sure what can I try further. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fundamentally, `JAVA_HOME` needs to be set to the Java *home*, not to the Java binary. This is a folder path that ends in `Home`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled `Java` the way it is written [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4772629):

> 1. Click on the Finder icon located in your dock
> 2. Click on Applications tab on the sidebar
> 3. In the Search box enter JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
> 4. This will find the JavaAppletPlugin.plugin file
> 5. Right click on JavaAppletPlugin.plugin and select Move to Trash

Then installed the recommended latest version for mac on the official `Java` website and it fixed the issue.